# what do some numbers and string affect on a code?

Tags: mysql, sql

what does the number '15' in the code below mean:

```
`land` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL default '15',
```

and when there is a string like here 'prod':

```
 `systemtype` varchar(15) NOT NULL default 'prod',
```

Comment: that `'15'` instead of `15` is a (dangerous) MySQL extension

Comment: Walter is right, putting a number between `''` quotes, basically converts it into a string (or varchar). The better way would be to remove the quotes (only with numbers).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't enter a value while inserting, the value of the field will become `15` or `prod`. Hence the term `default`.